# Price in sales_order_item equals a zero

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I did a test with two different versions of Magento 2 and got different results on both. I did the test using Magento 2.3.1 and Magento 2.3.5-p1.

In both cases I placed an order with a Configurable product without anything special.

**Magento 2.3.1: **

[image: Magento 2.3.1 print]

**Magento 2.3.5-p1**

[image: Magento 2.3.5-p1 print]

Looking at the code, I noticed that this condition exists in the file "vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total":

[image: Code Print]

If I remove this "isChildrenCalculated ()" condition from version 2.3.1 the behavior is similar to 2.3.5.

From what I noticed it has to do with it `['product_calculations'] = self::CALCULATE_CHILD` but I didn’t find where I configure it via the screen to change the behavior.

Does anyone know where I change this "product_calculations" value? Can anyone tell me why I have these two behaviors doing the same process in different versions?

Answer (score 0):

That has always been the behaviour. Unsure why you'd need to change it? The price is on the product order line associated with it.

There will be both a parent and child item in the order, only one will have the price against it

Comment: And why in version 2.3.5-p1 do we have the price on both lines? This is my problem, because in one version it has only one line and the other has both.

I wanted to understand why this behavior was occurring.